# How to use googlecharts gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, google-visualization

I am trying to use the googlecharts (http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/) gem. Where do you put the code to generate a chart (like `Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20]) )`? How do you display it?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling `Gchart.line()` simply returns a string that is the URL for the corresponding Google Chart image. E.g. `Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20])` returns `"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s:AjI9R&cht=lc&chs=300x200&chxr=0,0,70"`.

So, to display a chart on your page, you will need to create an image tag with a source of this generated URL. You can call Gchart directly from the view or set up the variable in your controller.

For example:

**Controller** `@line_chart = Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20])`

**View** `<%= image_tag(@line_chart) %>`

This will generate an image tag like so: `<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s:AjI9R&cht=lc&chs=300x200&chxr=0,0,70"/>`.

Comment: I am trying to run my google_charts.rb file from terminal which has the above code .I am unable to get the display of the chart on the browser. It would be great if you could help me in getting the chart display on the browser when I run my .rb file via terminal. i.e., ruby google_charts.rb command should display the chart on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the link provided isn't very informative in regards to use cases, but I'm almost positive that you need to make that call in a view.  Something like:

```
<%= Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20]) %>
```

will output the html required to create the chart.

Comment: It worked! Thanks.  I used <img src="<%= Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20]) %>" />